# How to connect to a database in Perl

Tags: database, eclipse, perl, postgresql

I am a newbie in Perl and Eclipse and i am trying to connect my Perl script to my database but it gives me an ERROR: "FILE DOES NOT EXIST"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Simple;
use DBI;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use constant {false=>0,true=>1};

my ( $exec_dir, $exec_file ) =
( Win32::GetFullPathName($0) =~ /^(.*)\\([^\\]*)$/ );

my $parmfil = $exec_dir . "\\parms\\parms.xml";
my $p_ref    = XMLin($parmfil);

my ($dsn,$dbusr,$dbpwd) = ( $p_ref->{"DSN"}
                            ,$p_ref->{"db_user"}
                                ,$p_ref->{"db_pwd"}
);
my $dbh = DBI->connect(  "dbi:ODBC:$dsn", $dbusr, $dbpwd )
        or die "SDM Database connect error - $DBI::errstr\n";
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = 1024 * 1024;

if (true)
{
    print "true\n";
}
```

Please Help me out.

Comment: What file doesn't exist? There should be a line number which will tell you where the problem is. The only file I can see is the XML file and I'm not clear what that has to do with databases or Exclipse.

Comment: this file: my $parmfil = $exec_dir . "\\parms\\parms.xml"; and it is there

Comment: So does it exist? Print the full path out and tell us. Then check it with `-e $parmfil` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Comment: turn on warnings with "use warnings;" it's good practice and might show up some issues.

Comment: oh, and `use strict;` too - but no issues are found in this script

Comment: This question has nothing to do with databases.

Answer (score 1):

I am more inclined to trust Perl that the file *doesn't* exist than your assurances that it *does*!

You should print the value of `$parmfil` and see if it's what you expect it to be.

You can also add this

```
print "\$parmfil %s exist\n", -f $parmfil ? 'DOES' : 'DOESN'T';
```

to get a "second opinion".

Answer (score -1):

This dosn't look right

```
my ( $exec_dir, $exec_file ) =
( Win32::GetFullPathName($0) =~ /^(.*)\\([^\\]*)$/ );
```

GetFullPathName in list contect will return pathname and filename as you require, but the reguler expression match will change that, can't see that its needed. If you want to manipulate the path then think its best to do so after the values have been returned.

Comment: It works, but is unneeded. The regex makes it called in scalar context, returning the full path/file as a single scalar, with the regex splitting it up. W/O the regex it would be called in list context, and return the path/file as separate elements, no regex needed.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
use strict;
use FindBin qw($Bin);

my $parmfil = $Bin . "/parms/parms.xml";
my $p_ref    = XMLin($parmfil);
```

Comment: dirname($0) . "/parms/parms.xml" would work just as well. General opionion is to [avoid FindBin](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=41213)

Comment: FindBin's bug you're talking about was fixed in 2011